# In Reactjs office addin .env file is not working

Tags: reactjs, process, .env

I have an office excel addin created in React in this I wanted to hide api keys I am using `.env` file for this my code in env file is `REACT_APP_API_KEY="1244556";` and I am using this `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY` in `APP.js` but the problem is that I am getting the error of process is not define. I use the same method in a simple React app and this work fine but in Office addin this is not working I tried almost everything

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY="1244556"
process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

remember I want the solution for addin not for simple react app

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or some other tool like vite etc.

Comment: I am using npm install -g yo generator-office